# Javascript : class instantiation with json

Tags: javascript, json, class, object

I have a class "House" like :

```
class House{
    constructor(params){
       this.clear();
       // this = {...params} // I know that don't work !!!
       //--
       // if(params.address !== undefined) this.address = {...params.address}
       //...
    }

    clear(){
      this.address = {
         number: null,
         street: null,
         zipcode: null,
         ton: null,
      }
      this.access = {
         doorcode: null,
         stair: null,
      }
    }
}
```

I want to  create a new instance of House and inject in constructor multiple json like :

```
const h = new House({address: { /* json */ }, access: { /* json */});
```

Or only one like :

```
const h = new House({access: { /* json */});
```

In constructor, am i obliged to check all values in "params" to insert in good properties (nested object)

I would like to avoid to create other classes like address and access and in the house constructor create new instance of each.
What's the best practice ?

Regards

Comment: Would `Object.assign(this,params)` work?

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) in the `constructor`, you can achieve this quite easily:

```js
class House {
  static get defaultAddress () {
    return {
      number: null,
      street: null,
      zipcode: null,
      town: null
    }
  }

  static get defaultAccess () {
    return {
      doorcode: null,
      stair: null
    }
  }

  constructor({ address = House.defaultAddress, access = House.defaultAccess } = {}) {
    this.clear()
    Object.assign(this.address, address)
    Object.assign(this.access, access)
  }

  clear () {
    const { defaultAddress, defaultAccess } = House

    Object.assign(this, { address: defaultAddress, access: defaultAccess })
  }
}

// no object
console.log(new House())
// empty object
console.log(new House({}))
// partial object
console.log(new House({ address: { number: 1, street: 'street', zipcode: 12345, town: 'town' } }))
// empty sub-objects
console.log(new House({ address: {}, access: {} }))
// partial sub-objects
console.log(new House({ address: { number: 1, street: 'street' }, access: { doorcode: 321 } }))
// complete object
console.log(new House({ address: { number: 1, street: 'street', zipcode: 12345, town: 'town' }, access: { doorcode: 321, stair: 3 } }))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%!important}
```

Comment: Good but not limited to specific keys. I'll mix with the answer below. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the parameters and set them manually. Then, to clear, remove all own properties (properties that aren't inherited).

```
class House {
  constructor(params) {
    // set data
    Object.assign(this, params);
  }

  clear() {
    for (let key in this) {
      if (this.hasOwnProperty(key))
        this[key] = undefined;  // or `delete this[key];`
    }
  }
}

let house = new House({type: "normal", height: 40});
console.log(house, house instanceof House);
```

---

Of course, you probably want to limit the input keys to a predefined set. You could store those keys in a static class variable and use them to loop through the properties in `constructor` and `clear`.

```js
class House {
  constructor(params) {
    // check for invalid properties
    Object.keys(params).forEach(key => {
      if (!House.keys.includes(key)) 
        throw `Invalid paramater ${key}`;
    });
    // set data
    Object.assign(this, params);
  }

  clear() {
    for (let key in House.keys) {
      if (this.hasOwnProperty(key))
        this[key] = undefined;  // or `delete this[key];`
    }
  }
}
House.keys = ['type', 'height'];

let house = new House({type: 'normal', height: 40});
console.log(house, house instanceof House);

let error = new House({helloWorld: true});
```

Comment: I thinks the best way to limit properties. I'll mix with previous answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a common namespace for your instance properties - similar to React's `props` pattern - you can also specify defaults for each instance you are creating:

```
const defaultProps = { address: {}, access: {} };

class House {
  constructor(props = {}) {
    this.props = {...defaultProps, ...props};
  }
  clear() {
    this.props = {...defaultProps};
  }
}
```

Comment: How can you export all from another file ?